# After Boot Repair, Windows 7 does not boot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, bootrepair

After I purchased my computer I followed these steps:

1. Installed Windows 7.
2. Installed Ubuntu.
3. There was no boot option, and Ubuntu automatically boots, leaving me no option to boot Windows.
4. I used Windows Repair to repair the MBR or whatever it is.
5. Now Ubuntu doesn't boot, and there is no option to boot Ubuntu.
6. Finally I used Boot Repair Disk.
7. Now there are options for Windows and Ubuntu.
8. Ubuntu boots properly.
9. Windows boots, but there is a blank purple screen after that.

Here is the link of my system boot information: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12095051

Comment: Did you select the purple when you installed Windows? The only colour screens you'd get if there was a problem would be a blue or black screen (BSODs)...

Comment: There are two options for you to boot into Windows (probably because silly Windows Repair unnecessarily built a BCD store on the system drive), does neither work? Try to change the two `chainloader +1` in grub.cfg to `ntldr /bootmgr` btw. Maybe also try delete the two `parttool ${root} hidden-` lines.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter if you want to the mircosoft bootloader or the grub bootloader I would suggest you to use the grub bootloader.

First of all, install [grub bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot). After that you can boot into your ubuntu installation, now rerun `update-grub`. The `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` should detect your Windows installation and add an entry in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. If we take a look at your diagnostics file, the `30_os-prober` has added some entry for your windows installation.

Maybe you should also edit `/etc/default/grub`, set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false`.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same steps except with Windows 10 and CentOS 7.  I got the same results except that Boot-Repair-Disk couldn't even find Windows 10.  The debugging info it posts on Ubuntu shows that it sees my Windows partitions on sda1 (100 MB), sda2 (67 GB - Windows 10), and sda3 (460 MB - hidden NTFS Windows Recovery Environment), but it doesn't create a boot entry for Windows.   My solution: manually create the grub entry in /etc/grub.d/40_custom:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
chainloader +1
}
```

then run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to install the changes.  After that the boot menu includes CentOS and Windows 10 and they both boot just fine.  Boot-Repair-Disk is a great concept, but it still needs work.

Note: the 2 in msdos2 is the Windows partition number - if Windows was installed on /dev/sda1 you'd use msdos1 instead.